# Column 'ITEMS_MASTER.QUANTITY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, inner-join

```
Select 
   ID.ITEM_MODEL,
   SUM(ID.AMOUNT) as Total_Amount,
   AVG(ID.RATE) as Avg_Rate,
   IM.QUANTITY 
From 
   ITEM_DETAILS ID 
inner join 
    ITEMS_MASTER IM on ID.ITEM_MODEL = IM.ITEM_MODEL 
    where IM.ITEM_MODEL='keyboard'
Group by 
    ID.ITEM_MODEL
```

I wrote above query, I want to extract data from two tables `ITEM_DETAILS` and `ITEMS_MASTERS` but when I run this it is showing me this error:

> Column 'ITEMS_MASTER.QUANTITY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone suggest me the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  IM.ITEM_MODEL, IM.QUANTITY,
        SUM(ID.AMOUNT) as Total_Amount,
        AVG(ID.RATE) as Avg_Rate
FROM    ITEMS_MASTER IM
        INNER JOIN ITEM_DETAILS ID ON ID.ITEM_MODEL = IM.ITEM_MODEL
WHERE   IM.ITEM_MODEL = 'keyboard'
GROUP BY IM.ITEM_MODEL, IM.QUANTITY
```

Generally speaking, when you have a parent table (ITEMS_MASTER) that has multiple rows from a child table (ITEM_DETAILS), you want to GROUP BY the columns in your parent table. This is slightly more logical and on some databases this performs better.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I believe that this is not what you're trying to do at all. Please explain in detail with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: I cant do SUM(IM.QUANTITY) because i have fixed value for `QUANTITY` against every `ITEM_MODEL`,i just want to extract that `QUANTITY` and display it in a single table.One more thing which i have now included in the question is the `where` clause which i forgot to specify earlier!

Comment: Then I believe @v4venletta is correct. If for every `ITEM_MODEL` record, there is a single `ITEMS_MASTER` record, you want to add `IM.QUANTITY` to the `GROUP BY` clause. If there are multiple `ITEMS_MASTER` records for each `ITEM_MODEL` record, then your `inner join` must be replaced with something else, as it would lead to double-counting (or triple-counting, etc) of `ID.AMOUNT` and `ID.RATE`.

Comment: Is there any way of just extract `QUANTITY` column from `ITEM_MASTER` and remain every other thing as it is because the query is working fine now but it `sums` every time when the value occurs in `ITEM_DETAILS` but i just want `QUANTITY` from `ITEMS_MASTERS`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding IM.QUANTITY to the group by clause,
Group by
ID.ITEM_MODEL,
IM.QUANTITY